# Format issue, system not printing variable from nested if loop

Tags: java, loops, nested-loops

I'm assuming its a simple  formating issue, however i cannt see it at the moment as I have been staring at this code for a few dozen hours now.
The intended ouput should show a string i.e. "add" or "or" instead of "null".
The string in question is functionR.

all input will be taken as helpful input.

```js
package src;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Decoder {
public static int Instructions [] = new int [] {0x022Da822, 0x8ef30018, 0x12a70004, 
0x02689820, 0xad930018, 0x02697824, 0xAD8ffff4,
0x018c6020, 0x02a4a825, 0x158ffff6, 0x8E59fff0};


public int address = 0x7A060;
public int startaddress=0x7A060;
public int opcode;
public int srcReg1;
public int srcReg2;
public int destreg;
public int sdReg;
public static int functcode;
public short offset;
int offaddress;
public int masks1 = 0x03e00000;
public int masks2dst= 0x001f0000;
public int masksDst = 0x0000f800;
public static int maskFunc = 0x0000003f;
public static int maskOpCode = 0xfc000000;
public int maskSDIform = 0x001f0000;
public int maskoffset=0x0000ffff;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
public static int opcodetest = (Instructions[3]&maskOpCode)>>>26;
public static int test = Instructions[0]>>>26;
public int srcReg1test = (Instructions[1]&masks1)>>>21;
public static int functcode0=(Instructions[0]&maskFunc);
public static int functcode3=(Instructions[3]&maskFunc);
public static int functcode5=(Instructions[5]&maskFunc);
public static int functcode7=(Instructions[7]&maskFunc);
public static int functcode8=(Instructions[8]&maskFunc);
public String functionR;

//not really a get method, just testing implementation of variables
/*
public int testingopcode()
{
 
 for(int x=0;x<Instructions.length;x++)
 {  
 opcode = Instructions[x]>>>26;
 //Just a little formal check
 System.out.println("Instructions in binary:"+(Integer.toBinaryString(Instructions[x]))+"\tOpCode:\t:::"+opcode+"\tsrc1:\t"+srcReg1test);
 }
 return opcode; 
}
*/

public void testrun()
{
 for(int x=0;x<Instructions.length;x++)

 {  
address = startaddress+(4*x);
opcode = Instructions[x]>>>26;
destreg = (Instructions[x]&masksDst)>>>11;
srcReg1=(Instructions[x]&masks1)>>>21;
srcReg2 =(Instructions[x]&masks2dst)>>>16;
sdReg=(Instructions[x]&masks2dst)>>>16;
functcode=(Instructions[x]&maskFunc);
offset=(short) (Instructions[x]&maskoffset);
offaddress=startaddress+offset;
String functionL = null;


if(opcode==0)

{ 
 {
  if(Integer.toHexString(functcode)=="20"){
 
 functionR = "add"; 
 continue;
  }
  else if(Integer.toHexString(functcode)=="22")
   {
    functionR = "sub";
    continue;
   }
  else if(Integer.toHexString(functcode)=="24")
  {
   functionR = "and";
   continue;
  }
  
  else if(Integer.toHexString(functcode)=="25")
  {
   functionR = "or";
   continue;
  }
  System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(address)+"\t"+functionR+"$"+destreg+", $"+srcReg1+", $"+srcReg2);
 }
 } 
else 
 {
 if(opcode == 35){
  functionL = "lw";
  System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(address)+"\t"+functionL+" $"+sdReg+", "+offset+", "+"("+srcReg1+")");
  continue;
  }
 
 else if(opcode == 4){
  functionL = "beq";
  System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(address)+"\t"+functionL+" $"+sdReg+", $"+srcReg1+", address "+Integer.toHexString(offaddress));
   continue;
 }
 
 else if (opcode == 43){
  functionL = "sw";
  System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(address)+"\t"+functionL+" $"+sdReg+", "+offset+", "+"("+srcReg1+")");
  continue;
 }
 
 
 else if (opcode == 5){
  functionL = "bne";
 System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(address)+"\t"+functionL+" $"+sdReg+", $"+srcReg1+", address "+Integer.toHexString(offaddress));
 continue;}
 }
}
 }




public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 Decoder Assemble = new Decoder();
 System.out.println(Decoder.test);
 System.out.println();
 System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(functcode0));
 System.out.println();
 System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(functcode3));
 System.out.println();
 System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(functcode5));
 System.out.println();
 System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(functcode7));
 System.out.println(); 
 System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(functcode8));
 System.out.println();
 Assemble.testrun();
 }

}
```

Actual output:

```js
22

20

24

20

25

7a060 null$21, $17, $13
7a064 lw $19, 24, (23)
7a068 beq $7, $21, address 7a064
7a06c null$19, $19, $8
7a070 sw $19, 24, (12)
7a074 null$15, $19, $9
7a078 sw $15, -12, (12)
7a07c null$12, $12, $12
7a080 null$21, $21, $4
7a084 bne $15, $12, address 7a056
7a088 lw $25, -16, (18)
```

intended:

```js
22

20

24

20

25

7a060 sub$21, $17, $13
7a064 lw $19, 24, (23)
7a068 beq $7, $21, address 7a064
7a06c add$19, $19, $8
7a070 sw $19, 24, (12)
7a074 and$15, $19, $9
7a078 sw $15, -12, (12)
7a07c add$12, $12, $12
7a080 null$21, $21, $4
7a084 or $15, $12, address 7a056
7a088 lw $25, -16, (18)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) No such thing as an "if loop". 2) Don't compare Strings using `==` or `!=`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that `==` checks if the two *object references* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.

Comment: 3) Your code as formatted is very difficult to read. Please consider editing your post and fixing your indentation style so that it is uniform and consistent. I usually avoid using tabs for indenting (site software often doesn't play well with tabs) and indent each code block 4 spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'll see if the  the equals method behaves more appropriately. I will also manage the indentation to make the question/code more readable..